# Failed to start Video surface

Tags: c++, qt5, qmediaplayer

When I start four `QMediaplayer` in qt5 to play '`v4l2:///dev/video0`' and so on. It plays the video on screen but at terminal it gives:

```
Failed to start Video surface
```

I am not able to understand why I get this message.
Any help will be appreciated.